# He was saved a lot of money by the decision

Tags: passive-voice

> a. The decision saved him a lot of money. 
> b. He was saved a lot of money by the decision.

Is b. the correct passive version of a.?

Comment: Technically correct, but unnatural. It sounds like a grammar mistake until I get to the end and think it through.

Comment: I think the "Direct object" of the verb "to save" is "money" and "the indirect object" is "him". So, the passive version might be: 

A lot of money was saved for him by the decision.

Comment: @gotube Are you sure it's "technically correct"? I think that's assuming that when an active sentence has both indirect and direct objects, you can _always_ produce a passive sentence by using the indirect object as the subject of the passive sentence. Is this assumption without any exception?

Comment: @listeneva I was speaking only about that one sentence, and it's correct. I was not speaking about sentences of some type, nor assuming anything using logic. It's just my native speaker sense of the sentence, and that's all you asked. If you want to know if it's always possible to form a passive sentence in the way you describe, then ask a new question about that specifically.

Comment: @gotube I thought you were saying it didn't sound correct to your "native speaker sense of the sentence", although it might be technically correct given that the indirect object was used as the subject of the passive. Maybe I have misunderstood you.

Comment: @listeneva I get what you're saying. No, I didn't mean that. It's correct, but hard to understand at first. To be precise, it is an example of a *[garden-path sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence)*, which means a grammatically correct sentence that starts in such a way that people parse it incorrectly. For example, "The horses run past the barn fell." It's hard for native speakers to understand it at first, but after explaining that it means, "The horses that someone ran past the barn fell down", it's easier to parse correctly.

Comment: @gotube Actually, I suspected that b. was not something native speakers would ever say, and thus that it was incorrect. I also know a similar ditransitive construction that doesn't seem to work in the passive. Can you passivize _the task took him an hour_ and say _he was taken an hour by the task_?

Comment: @listeneva No. That last sentence is wrong. My feeling (not knowledge) is that "to take somebody some time" is a fixed idiomatic structure, not a transitive verb form at all. Even the simpler: *The task took an hour* cannot be made passive: **An hour was taken (by the task)*. It may be the case that "an hour" is an adverbial complement, or something, rather than an object.

Comment: @gotube But I'm sure "him" in that sentence _is_ an indirect object, "him" being in the accusative case. As for it being a "fixed idiomatic structure", why are idioms banned from being passivized? Are they really? "Close tabs should be kept on him" does work, using the idiom "keep close tabs on".

Comment: @gotube you wrote that it's technically correct, but a "garden-path sentence" that people parse incorrectly, and so seems wrong. What is the solution to the puzzle, how do you unravel the garden path more clearly?

Comment: @Sam I'm unclear what you're asking. Do you mean, *as a reader*, how do you unravel the correct parsing of the sentence? Or do you mean *as the writer* how do you rewrite it to be easily intelligible?

Comment: @listeneva I didn't say anything about idioms in general. I said that I felt "take time", alone, was fixed somehow -- part of its idiosyncratic behaviour. I agree that "him" looks a lot like an indirect object, intransitive verbs can have indirect objects, so that doesn't help us.

Comment: @gotube when I read that sentence, it sounds like a grammar mistake.  Which was your first comment also.  But then you say it's not a mistake, it's a garden-path.  If that's true, what is your interpretation of the garden path?  I guess, as a _reader_.   (Although, by explaining it, the resulting explanation might also be the answer for the _writer_,  depending on how it looks)

Comment: @Sam No guarantees --not everyone can read all GP sentences-- but here goes. It has the exact same meaning as the sentence above it. The "garden path" that you want to force your brain to *swerve away from* is, "He was saved" meaning "Something saved him", with "him" as the direct object of "save". In the active sentence, "a lot of money" is the direct object. "Him" is the indirect object. It's common to read the subject of a passive sentence as the active direct object of the verb, and that's the "garden path". "Saved a lot of money" is a constituent phrase. Hope that helps.

Comment: @gotube if flipping the sentence around from active to passive, it would go from "the decision saved money" to "Money was saved by the decision".  Not "he was saved by the decision".  If "him" was the indirect object in the first sentence, it would not become the subject during this conversion from active to passive.

Comment: @Sam Indirect objects in active sentences can be the subject of equivalent passive sentences: "*Tim threw the ball to Mary*" can be expressed as *"Mary was thrown the ball (by Tim)*".